# Android App crash while loading SharedPreferences 'getBoolean'

Tags: java, android

i want to save the settings from my game(bgMusic, sounds and vibration) but while loading the app crashes when starting. 
The code is:

```
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private boolean bgMusicToggleState, soundToggleState, vibratorToggleState;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pause_dialog);
    dialog.hide();
    initDialog();

    this.preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(GAME_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    this.editor = preferences.edit();
    ...

}
...
public void saveMusicSettings(){
    editor.putBoolean("bgMusicToggleState", bgmusic_toggle.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
}
public void saveVibratorSettings(){
    editor.putBoolean("vibratorToggleState", vibrateToggle.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
}

public void saveSoundSettings(){
    editor.putBoolean("soundToggleState", sounds_toggle.isChecked());
    editor.commit();
}
...
private void initDialog(){
/// The App crashes here
    bgMusicToggleState = preferences.getBoolean("bgMusicToggleState", false);


    continue_Button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
    restart_Button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.restart_button);
    exit_Button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.exit_button);

    continue_Button.setOnClickListener(pauseClick);
    exit_Button.setOnClickListener(pauseClick);
    restart_Button.setOnClickListener(pauseClick);

    bgmusic_toggle = (ToggleButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.backgroundsound_toggle);
    bgmusic_toggle.setChecked(bgMusicToggleState);
    bgmusic_toggle.setOnClickListener(toggleClickListener);

    sounds_toggle = (ToggleButton) dialog.findViewById(R.id.soundtoggle);
    sounds_toggle.setChecked(soundToggleState);
    sounds_toggle.setOnClickListener(toggleClickListener);

    vibrateToggle = (ToggleButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.vibrate_toggle);
    vibrateToggle.setChecked(vibratorToggleState);
    vibrateToggle.setOnClickListener(toggleClickListener);


}
```

--> the save settings are called in the toggleClickListener
It does't make difference if the preferenes and the editor are in the initMethod...
Is it maybe then the ToggleButtons are in the Dialog or must I do this in one Method?
I hope you can help me.
Thanks!

Comment: please post crash logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `initDialog` after you initialize the `SharedPreference` object, not before. 
Change

```
initDialog();
this.preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(GAME_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
this.editor = preferences.edit();
```

to

```
this.preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(GAME_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
this.editor = preferences.edit();
initDialog();
```